# relative path for hc.parameters.file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Does anybody know how can I set relative path as a **hc.parameters.file** value in Jmeter?

I'm talked about this article - https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed

```
hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
```

This works fine if I run jmeter from the bin directory, but it fails to open mentioned file if I run it from another place.

It also works in case I specify full path.

But I need to have same Jmeter instance on several machines with different file structure (and different OS), so what I'm looking for is how to specify some relevant path for mentioned parameter.

I've found following in the jmeter.log:

```
2015/05/13 16:24:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=C:\jmeter2.13 
2015/05/13 16:24:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =C:\jmeter2.13\bin 
2015/05/13 16:24:58 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =C:\jmeter2.13\bin
```

and tried to set hc.parameters.file as:
    hc.parameters.file=${JMeterHome}/bin/hc.parameters
but this doesn't solve an issue.

Is there an option to set the relative path or the current dir and full path are the only option?

Comment: how are you running jmeter from "another place" ?

Comment: for example: `c:\Temp>c:\jmeter2.13\bin\jmeter.bat` in this case i got `ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HttpClientDefaultParameters: Problem loading properties java.io.FileNotFoundException: hc.parameters (The system cannot find the file specified)` trying to run some test.

Comment: Ah,ok.  `${JMeterHome}` wont work on windows, try `%JMeterHome%` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use path relative to the **current working directory** or the absolute path. Here is an example:
`jmeter -n -t src/test/jmeter/servicesPerfTestPlan.jmx -j ~/Library/Logs/jmeter.log -Jhc.parameters.file=src/test/jmeter/hc.parameters`

You just need to ensure that hc.parameters file is in a predictable place (probably somewhere in your project) and make sure to change directory to, for example, the project root before running. The right place to do it is your build script or you could create a launcher script that would change current directory to your project root or JMeter test plan directory, etc.

It would work fine:

```
2015/10/28 12:22:30 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HttpClientDefaultParameters: Reading httpclient parameters from src/test/jmeter/hc.parameters 
2015/10/28 12:22:30 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HttpClientDefaultParameters: Defining http.connection.stalecheck as true (Boolean)
```

The second option if above does not work for you for some reason is to calculate absolute path for `hc.parameters` dynamically in your build/launcher script.